# Access 2016 Update Query

Tags: ms-access

Can anyone help me with an access update query please?

It was working fine when the DB was an MDB file but since upgrading to ACCDB, the query won't run and gives:

> Operation must use updatable query

However, it will run if opened in design view first and then opened from design view.  Data is displayed as expected.

The DB security is confirmed as trusted and I have set the trust locations accordingly.

The SQL for this query is:

```
UPDATE (tblStock INNER JOIN tblStockPricing ON tblStock.StockID = tblStockPricing.StockID) INNER JOIN tblWorkings ON tblStock.StockID = tblWorkings.wkgStockControlStockID SET tblWorkings.wkgPartNo = tblStock.Description, tblWorkings.wkgStockCode = tblStock.StockCode & tblStock.SortOrder & ' * ', tblWorkings.wkgTradePrice = tblStockPricing.InternalPrice
WHERE (((tblWorkings.wkgStockCode) Is Not Null) AND ((tblWorkings.DesignID)=15726) AND ((tblWorkings.wkgStockControlStockID) Is Not Null));
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was tracked down to my access front end linked tables to a backend SQL server where the tables didn't have a primary key.

The primary key was present in the original MDB file but after upgrading to ACCDB file, the primary keys are not present and need to be manually setup again.

Hope this help others.